# Ideal, generated by elements in subalgebra J, has property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let R - associative algebra, I - ideal of R, J - ideal of I.
How can I prove, that ideal $ (J)_{R} $  of К, generated elements in subalgebra J, has property: $ (J)_{R}^3 \subseteq J $ ?

I know, by definition, that:

> $ (J)_{R} = J \oplus RJ \oplus JR \oplus RJR $
>
> $ (J)_{R}^3 = \left\{ \sum a_{1}a_{2}a_{3} | a_{i} \in (J)_{R} \right\}$
>
> Ideal $ (J)_{R} $ of R, generated by J,contained in any ideal of R, containing J

I'm stuck at this point. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question, it comes down to showing that $j_1j_2j_3 \in J$ if $j_1, j_2, j_3$ in $J$. That is an easy consequence of the definition of an ideal.

Comment: Okey. Definition of an ideal is: subring I of ring R called ideal, if it withstands left and right multiplication,i.e $ IR + RI \subseteq R $. How can I show, that $ j_{1}j_{2}j_{3}.\in J $. Do I use multiplication elements in ideal? I'm a little confused